# Is it a good web design practice to use a YouTube video URL on another website in a <video> element?

Tags: html, video, youtube, web-hosting

I am currently making a website, in which I need to have a video.
I can do it the conventional way (see below):

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<video src='video/video.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
</body>
<html>
```

Or I can host the video on youtube, and use the server's mp4 URL, like so:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<video src='https://r8---sn-uxanug5-5qaz.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=o7VZW_y0Kpi24QKPwrqACQ&itag=22&c=WEB&key=yt6&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=0&sparams=dur,ei,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,expire&lmt=1507492245875618&id=o-AKYOyESA6jbC2iAoVVBgDKz1LfNySwouDQf8aG9frY3n&ms=au,rdu&mt=1532605714&mv=m&expire=1532627459&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mime=video/mp4&ip=101.166.164.147&initcwndbps=753750&dur=169.784&fvip=2&mm=31,29&signature=7F387ED416BB909F7158F01B132A238B12C520B8.D3DE10E5AD366B8909BC9E8A3DA6B783BEDFCEDA&pl=18&mn=sn-uxanug5-5qaz,sn-ntqe7n7l' type='video/mp4'>
</body>
<html>
```

I am only a junior web developer (I am less than 18 years old), I just need to know from someone who has more experience in the field if this is a good idea.

Comment: Why would you want to use the servers URL when they offer an embed?

Comment: "I don't know if this is a violation of their ToS or anything, I just want to know if it is ok legally" — Since the terms of service are an important part of what is OK legally … that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Putting the legality to one side, you've got a technically flawed bit of code there. That URL will only work for a certain amount of time before it expires, in this case, at Thursday, July 26, 2018 5:50:59 PM

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking a legal question, not a question about programming as defined by the Help Center. Please ask on https://law.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can generally embed any video from YouTube in your blog, unless the owner has turned off embedding. But you need to be careful as sometimes people upload videos they don't have permission to share

The licensing explicitly permits this for all videos not just creative commons

"to each user of the Service, a worldwide, non-exclusive, royalty-free licence to access your Content through the Service, and to use, reproduce, distribute, prepare derivative works of, display and perform such Content to the extent permitted by the functionality of the Service and under these Terms."

Comment: The text you quote only allows the user to access "their Content". Are you sure that allows visitors to their website to access the content that way too? (In general, Stackoverflow is a **terrible** place to seek legal advice).

Comment: Mostly Yes, but there's some videos that require you to go to youtube for you to watch them

Comment: "but there's some videos that require you to go to youtube for you to watch them" — You missed my point entirely.